# How to do url Rewriting In umbraco

Tags: .net, umbraco, umbraco6

I'm doing project in Umbraco CMS. I had created all necessary pages in this Umbraco. i published it. But i want to rewrite my url of each page . Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/umbraco/OurUmbraco/blob/master/OurUmbraco.Site/config/UrlRewriting.config

i try with this. get a better solution. make a try on the above

Comment: this is solution help me much

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution for your question.

Please Visit http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/packaging/package-actions/community-made-package-actions/add-an-url-rewrite-rule